# Missing keyword in nested CASE WHEN statement

Tags: sql, keyword

Experiencing error `Missing keyword` appear and highlighting on my second line of query. I tried to remove the extra case when but still happened.

```
CASE WHEN NVL(BAT_WK02,0)>=NVL(TARGET_BAT,0) THEN 
    CASE WHEN NVL(RMO_ENTITLED_WK01,0)>0 THEN NVL(SKU_SALES_WK02,0) >= NVL(TARGET_SKU,0) THEN NVL (TARGET_SKU,0) * 1 ELSE NVL(SKU_SALES_WK02,0) *1 
                             WHEN NVL(RMO_ENTITLED_WK01,0)=0 THEN NVL(SKU_SALES_WK02,0) >= NVL(TARGET_SKU,0) THEN NVL (TARGET_SKU,0) * 0.50 ELSE NVL (SKU_SALES_WK02) * 0.50 END
                     ELSE 0 END RMO_ENTITLED_SKU_02,
```

Any suggestions to help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN NVL(BAT_WK02,0)>=NVL(TARGET_BAT,0) THEN 
( 
   CASE WHEN NVL(RMO_ENTITLED_WK01,0)>0 THEN NVL(SKU_SALES_WK02,0) >= NVL(TARGET_SKU,0) 
        WHEN <--Here Statement missing--> 
        THEN NVL (TARGET_SKU,0) * 1 ELSE NVL(SKU_SALES_WK02,0) *1 END 
)
WHEN NVL(RMO_ENTITLED_WK01,0)=0 THEN NVL(SKU_SALES_WK02,0) >= NVL(TARGET_SKU,0) 
WHEN <--Here Statement missing--> 
THEN NVL (TARGET_SKU,0) * 0.50 ELSE NVL (SKU_SALES_WK02) * 0.50 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Basically I got three things to check, first if the BAT_WK02 is greater then the TARGET_BAT, then proceed to check whether RMO_ENTITLED_WK01 got value (achieved wk_01 target) or not (failed to achieve wk01 target). If RMO_ENTITLED_WK01 got value, then further to check whether SKU_SALES_WK02 value whether it hits the max reimbursement, if yes, use the max cap (TARGET_SKU) multiply 1 otherwise use the sales figure (SKU_SALES_WK02) * 1; If RMO_ENTITLED_WK01 is 0 (not achieve wk01 target) then it should (SKU_SALES_WK02) * 0.50

please let me know if need more clarification, thanks.

Comment: Can you give some sample data and expected output

Comment: Sure.
IF RMO_ENTITLED_WK01 = 5; SALES_CAP = 10; SALES_WK02 = 15
THEN SALES_CAP * 1
IF RM0_ENTITLED_WK01 = 5; SALES_CAP = 20; SALES_WK02 = 15
THEN SALES_WK02 *1
IF RMO_ENTITLED_WK01 = 0; SALES_CAP = 10; SALES_WK02 =15
THEN SALES_CAP * 0.5
IF RMO_ENTITLED_WK01 = 0; SALES_CAP = 20; SALES_WK02 = 15
THEN SALES_WK02 * 0.5

hope this helps!

Comment: the result of the multiply 1 or 0.5 will be RMO_ENTITLED_WK02. this case when is to check if the salesperson hit target for two consecutive weeks it reward will be 1 otherwise will be 0.5. And the tricky part is it need to check the cap as it can't be over rewarded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a 'when' keyword for every 'then' keyword in your query, you have one missing on line 2-3.

CASE WHEN NVL(BAT_WK02,0)>=NVL(TARGET_BAT,0) THEN CASE **WHEN** NVL(RMO_ENTITLED_WK01,0)>0 **THEN** NVL(SKU_SALES_WK02,0) >= NVL(TARGET_SKU,0) **THEN** NVL (TARGET_SKU,0) * 1 ELSE ...

You have a nested 'case when' by the way, but I guess that was supposed to be there